# Searching for a file with different keywords

Tags: excel, vba, file, search

I am writing a macro that will find a file and attach it to an email.

So far, the hacked together code i have, is designed as follows
- Start in specified directory
- Generate list of folders in directory > exported to cells on a temporarily created worksheet
- Loops through this list of folders, searching for the existence of a folder (all these subfolders are labled by job numbereg. /13456/)
- When it finds the numbered job folder, it then checks for one more subfolder, "drawings"
- If the folder labled "drawings" exists, the file we want will be in there.
- If the folder labled "drawings" doesnt exist, the file we want will be in the numbered job folder.

Now it's here that im getting stuck.
At the moment, my code looks for a file in these two locations with the search term "*FIRST*.pdf".

I would also like to search with other phrases, eg "*UPPER*.pdf", "*1st*.pdf", "*UF*.pdf".

Would the best way to do this be a loop that refers to cells on a table, therefore requiring another temporary sheet be created and more cells filled in? or is there a tricky way this can be done with loop code without needing that?

Again, my code is hacked together quite roughly, as im sort of learning as i go.
Also the requirements of the macro keep changing as the people im making it for realise what else can be done with it, so the logic hasnt been designed all at once. :\

```
Sub Concrete_Order()
'code deleted from above area in question


Dim foldersearchpath As String, ctr As Integer, UFPLANNAME As String, UFPLANpdf As String

ctr = 1

Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "asdf"

Path = "K:\drafting\jobs\1DETAILING\"   'always have "\" at end

FirstDir = Dir(Path, vbDirectory)

    Do Until FirstDir = ""
        If (GetAttr(Path & FirstDir) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(ctr, 1).Value = Path & FirstDir
            ctr = ctr + 1
        End If

        FirstDir = Dir()  
    Loop

Sheets("asdf").Select

ctr = ctr - 1 'counter correction

    Do Until ctr = 2
        foldersearchpath = Range("A" & ctr) & "\" & jobNumber & "\"

            Dim FldrCheck As String, FldrCheck2 As String, UFPlanFile As String

            FldrCheck = Dir(foldersearchpath, vbDirectory)

                 If Len(FldrCheck) > 0 Then

                        FldrCheck2 = Dir(foldersearchpath & "drawings\", vbDirectory)

                             If Len(FldrCheck2) > 0 Then

                                   foldersearchpath = foldersearchpath & "drawings\"
                                   file = Dir(foldersearchpath & "*FIRST*.pdf")


                                           If file <> "" Then
                                                  UFPlanFile = foldersearchpath & file
                                                  GoTo planfileFound
                                           Else
                                                  GoTo UFPLAN_MANUAL_attach
                                           End If


                             Else

                                  file = Dir(foldersearchpath & "*FIRST*.pdf")

                                       If file <> "" Then

                                           UFPlanFile = foldersearchpath & file
                                           GoTo planfileFound
                                       Else

                                            GoTo UFPLAN_MANUAL_attach
                                       End If



                            End If


                 Else

                 End If

        ctr = ctr - 1
    Loop

On Error GoTo 0

UFPLAN_MANUAL_attach:

Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

 With fd

      .AllowMultiSelect = False
      .Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).InitialFileName = foldersearchpath
      .Title = "Could not find Upper Floor Plan, please locate..."
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "Adobe PDF", "*.pdf"
      .Filters.Add "John File", "*.god"
      .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

      If .Show = True Then 'user clicked ok
           UFPlanFile = .SelectedItems(1) 'replace txtFileName with your textbox
      End If

 End With


planfileFound:

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("asdf").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


On Error GoTo 0

'code deleted from after
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Programming languages have a inbuild Class for dynamic Lists. Vba has the Collection class. You can add items with .Add and retrieve items with (i) or use "For Each" to loop through each item

```
Sub Concrete_Order()
    'code deleted from above area in question


    Dim foldersearchpath As String, ctr As Integer, UFPLANNAME As String, UFPLANpdf As String

    Dim foundDirectories As Collection
    Set foundDirectories = New Collection


    Path = "K:\drafting\jobs\1DETAILING\"   'always have "\" at end

    FirstDir = Dir(Path, vbDirectory)

    Do Until FirstDir = ""
        If (GetAttr(Path & FirstDir) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
            foundDirectories.Add Path & FirstDir
        End If

        FirstDir = Dir()
    Loop


    Dim possibleFileNames As Collection
    Set possibleFileNames = New Collection

    possibleFileNames.Add "*FIRST*.pdf"
    possibleFileNames.Add "UPPER.pdf"
    possibleFileNames.Add "1st.pdf"
    possibleFileNames.Add "UF.pdf"


    Dim currentDirectory

    For Each currentDirectory In foundDirectories

        foldersearchpath = currentDirectory & "\" & jobNumber & "\"

        Dim FldrCheck As String, FldrCheck2 As String, UFPlanFile As String

        FldrCheck = Dir(foldersearchpath, vbDirectory)

        If Len(FldrCheck) > 0 Then

            FldrCheck2 = Dir(foldersearchpath & "drawings\", vbDirectory)

            If Len(FldrCheck2) > 0 Then
                foldersearchpath = foldersearchpath & "drawings\"
            End If

            Dim possibleFileName

            For Each possibleFileName In possibleFileNames
                file = Dir(foldersearchpath & possibleFileName)

                If file <> "" Then

                    UFPlanFile = foldersearchpath & file

                    GoTo planfileFound

                End If
            Next

            GoTo UFPLAN_MANUAL_attach

        End If

    Next

    On Error GoTo 0

UFPLAN_MANUAL_attach:

    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

     With fd

          .AllowMultiSelect = False
          .Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).InitialFileName = foldersearchpath
          .Title = "Could not find Upper Floor Plan, please locate..."
          .Filters.Clear
          .Filters.Add "Adobe PDF", "*.pdf"
          .Filters.Add "John File", "*.god"
          .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

          If .Show = True Then 'user clicked ok
               UFPlanFile = .SelectedItems(1) 'replace txtFileName with your textbox
          End If

     End With


planfileFound:



    On Error GoTo 0

'code deleted from after
End Sub
```

Comment: I like collections too. For this purpose (simply being a static enumerable), an array also works quite nicely (`For Each possibleFileName in Array("*FIRST*,"UPPER","1st",etc):...:Next`)

Comment: wow really appreciate that! will definitely drop it in tomorrow and run some tests! thanks for the quick response and for updating the code!

Comment: oh, and you have got rid of the temporary sheet. nice one, im learning heaps from this. thanks again!